# How to pass multiple args to a Sass Mixin: a list and named variable

Tags: css, sass, scss-mixins

I'm using a mixin for outputting a default transition timing-function, duration and a variable number of properties.

**Current Mixin:**

```
@mixin fast-transition($properties...) { 
  transition-duration: 0.1s;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);
  @if length($properties) > 1 {
    transition-property: $properties;
  } @else {
    transition-property: all;
  }
  :global(.browser-ie) & {
    transition: none;
  }
}
```

**Current Usage:**

```
@include fast-transition(background-color, color);
```

**Current Result:**

```
.el {
  transition-duration: 0.1s;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);
  transition-property: background-color, color;
}
.browser-ie .el {
  transition: none;
}
```

---

What I'd like to be able to do is specify the usage of the `transition: none` code block, possibly through an @if statement.

**Desired Mixin (Doesn't work)**

```
@mixin fast-transition($properties..., $ieTransition) {
  transition-duration: 0.1s;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);
  @if length($properties) > 1 {
    transition-property: $properties;
  } @else {
    transition-property: all;
  }
  @if not ($ieTransition) {
    :global(.browser-ie) & {
      transition: none;
    }
  }
}
```

**Usage: (Doesn't work)**

```
@include fast-transition((background-color, color), $ieTransition);
```

**Desired Output**:

```
.el {
  transition-duration: 0.1s;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);
  transition-property: background-color, color;
}
```

---

**Working Version - From Yunzen's Answer**

```
@mixin fast-transition($ie: false, $props: "all") {
  transition-duration: 0.1s;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);
  transition-property: #{$props};

  @if not($ie) {
    :global(.browser-ie) & {
      transition: none;
    }
  }
}
```

```
@include fast-transition($props: "background-color, color", $ie: true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must put the arbitrary arguments at the end of the mixin's arguments list (See the [doc](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/mixin#taking-arbitrary-arguments))

Try this instead: It uses named arguments in the `@include` arguments list and options arguments ([doc](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/mixin#optional-arguments)) in the `@mixin definition`

```
@mixin fast-transition($ieTransition: false, $properties: "all") {
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);
  transition-property: $properties;
  
  @if not($ieTransition) {
    :global(.browser-ie) & {
      transition: none;
    }
  }
}
```

to use it do this

```
.el-all {
  // use all for transition properties and no transition for IE
  @include fast-transition();
)
// or
.el-no-ie {
  // use $properties for transition properties and no transition for IE
  @include fast-transition($properties: 'background-color, color");
)
// or
.el-ie {
  // use $properties for transition properties and transition for IE
  @include fast-transition($properties: 'background-color, color", $ieTransition: true);
)
```

See this demonstration https://codepen.io/HerrSerker/pen/dyXEvWK?editors=1100

Comment: There was a minor tweak I made which was to wrap $properties with #{} to prevent the apostrophes from being output in the CSS.

Besides from that it's working as expected now, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
@mixin fast-transition($ieTransition: false, $properties...) {
  ...
}
@include fast-transition(background-color, color, $ieTransition: some_value);
```

Comment: This didn't work:
`SassError: required parameters must precede variable-length parameters`